# How do I pass a string array as function argument

Tags: c++

I am having an issue in passing a string array to a function.[this is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGg8K.png)

Can anybody help me out with this and tell whats the error with my program that I am getting such an output.
[here is my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jHM8B.png)

Thank You

Comment: 1. Don't post links to code 2. Don't post images of code

Comment: 3. `&database[30]` is invoking undefined behavior, as you are accessing the 31st element of a 30 element array

Comment: When making a C++ program, you should generally use the `<cname>` version of C headers, instead of the `<name.h>` version; in this case, `<cstdlib>` instead of `<stdlib.h>`.

Answer (score 0):

You're passing a pointer to 31st element of the array. That's why it crashes.

Arrays are indexed from 0.

Try passing whole array:

`loop(5, database)`

We generally do not pass arrays into functions, but pointers, `std::array` or `std::vector`.

Comment: what will my function parameters look like

Answer (score 0):

When you call the function looping, just do `looping(5,database);`